# CSS not loading properly magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

CSS not loading properly in magento2. Getting below error:

```
NameError: variable @button__shadow-active is undefined

in _buttons.less
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use wampserver  ?

1. Go to your wampserver icon and click  on it  and than

***Apache->apache modules->rewrite_module[enable this]***

After this start all services and check it ........

Answer (score 0):

Css not loaded properly means static content rendering problem so,

Remove cache,page_cache,view_preprocessed from var table

Give full permissions to var folder

Run static command in magento root folder php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

now Roload the site

Answer (score 0):

CSS not loading properly due to static deploy not push the file to pub/static directory.

You have to follow the below steps.

1. `rm -rf var/*`
2. `rm -rf pub/static/*`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
4. `chmod -R 7777 var pub/static`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says your less variable is missing and not found. 
It means these are possible reasons for your error:

- Invalid **.less** variable declaration.
- If you are importing variables from another file - you have an invalid declaration of that file in the **XML** or you didn't import that file on your less file with `@import "custom-variables.less";`
- There is a typo in your main **.less** file

Without code, there are only guesses. Please provide us a code so we could check it more precisely. Also, check your .log files there can be some hints.

Answer (score 0):

- First Replace .htaccess.sample with .htaccess in root
- Add .htaccess in pub/static 
  https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/pub/static/.htaccess
- Edit & Replace Apache config file & replace given details below.
  sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

From

```
<Directory /var/www/>

     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

     AllowOverride None

     Require all granted

</Directory>
```

From

```
<Directory /var/www/>

     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

     AllowOverride All

     Require all granted

</Directory>
```

- sudo service apache2 restart
- rm -rf var/cache/*
- rm -rf var/generation/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- chmod -R 777 pub var
  This will solve your css issues, admin 404 issues , link/url 404 issue , version-xxx issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

1. set permission on `/var` and `/pub` folders to `777`
2. ssh using this command

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```

Comment: Some explanation about why someone should "try this" would make this a better answer.